# Using a java.util.Scanner from within a method causes a runtime error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Why would the following code give me a runtime error? It gives me a `NoSuchElementException` when the method is called the second time. It works fine if I delete the call to `stdin.close()`, but then Eclipse gives a warning that the resource is not closed.

### Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class st {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("First call");
    getInt("Enter first int (1-10): ");
    System.out.println("Second call");
    getInt("Enter second int (1-10): ");
  }

  /**
   * Reads an integer number from the keyboard.
   *
   * @param  prompt    the string to display as a prompt.
   * @return           the integer number entered at the keyboard.
   */
  public static int getInt(String prompt) {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print(prompt);
    int val = stdin.nextInt();

    stdin.close();
    return(val);
  }
}

// END
```

### Output:

```
>java st
First call
Enter first int (1-10): 5
Second call
Enter second int (1-10): Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
        at st.getInt(st.java:24)
        at st.main(st.java:9)

>
```

### Version:

```
>java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)

>
```

Thanks

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS @MikePrecup says, when you close the first Scanner (`stdin`), you are also closing `System.in`, therefore the second Scanner can no longer read from it and a `NoSuchElementException` is thrown.

However, I would suggest another option: use a single scanner declaring it as a class variable.

```
public class st {

  private static Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("First call");
    getInt("Enter first int (1-10): ");
    System.out.println("Second call");
    getInt("Enter second int (1-10): ");
  }

  /**
   * Reads an integer number from the keyboard.
   *
   * @param  prompt    the string to display as a prompt.
   * @return           the integer number entered at the keyboard.
   */
  public static int getInt(String prompt) {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    int val = stdin.nextInt();

    stdin.close();
    return(val);
  }
}

// END
```

Comment: Agreed that this is a better option in this case. I'll leave my answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that closing `stdin` also closes the underlying stream, which is, in this case, `System.in`. Hence, you won't be able to get any more input from it. You'll need to prevent it from closing. The easiest option is probably to wrap `System.in` with a [`CloseShieldInputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html).