# Why do I get a "No line found" Exception in this code?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

The following method causes a `No line found Exception`:

```
private static String getRebaseAnswer(boolean isFirst, boolean isLast) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to (c)ontinue, (s)kip this commit, or"
            + " change this commit's (m)essage?");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer;
    while (true) {
        answer = in.nextLine(); // <--- This Line
        if (answer.equals("c") || answer.equals("m")) {
            in.close();
            return answer;
        } else if (answer.equals("s") && !isFirst && !isLast) {
            in.close();
            return answer;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Would you like to (c)ontinue, (s)kip this commit, or"
                    + " change this commit's (m)essage?");
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the method in this method:

```
...
String answer;
Scanner in;
currHead = branchHeads.get(arg);
while (toRebase != null) {
    System.out.println("Currently replaying:");
    toRebase.getNode().printInfo();
    answer = getRebaseAnswer(isFirst, toRebase.getParent() == null); // <--- This Line
...
```

What is causing the error?? Shouldn't the scanner wait for me to input a line before continuing the `getRebaseAnswer` method? A different method in my code has the exact same structure as the above method and encounters no problems. I've checked multiple other posts about this problem but their suggestions are all not pertinent to this problem or do not solve it.

This method runs with no problems:

```
private static boolean handleDangerous() {
    System.out.println("Warning: The command you entered may alter the files in your"
            + " working directory. Uncommitted changes may be lost. Are you sure you"
            + " want to continue? (yes/no)");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer;
    while (true) {
        answer = in.nextLine();
        if (answer.equals("yes")) {
            in.close();
            return true;
        } else if (answer.equals("no")) {
            in.close();
            return false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a valid answer, please enter (yes/no).");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are closing the stream.Remove `in.close()`

Comment: Shouldn't i close my scanners though? @singhakash

Comment: probabily related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256945/using-a-java-util-scanner-from-within-a-method-causes-a-runtime-error

Comment: Okay well if the close is the problem, then why is another method in my code working if it has the same structure? @singhakash

Comment: i think you are calling this method multiple times.

Comment: @Prashant Yes, I am but the first call throws the error..

Comment: i don't think first time you will get the same.might be you are closing in main also or in some other method which called before to this method. can you show your full code

Comment: @Prashant Sorry I can't do that, the code is for a school project and doing that would break policies.

Comment: you might be calling some other method before calling to this method which is closing Stream

Comment: @Prashant I am, but shouldn't every scanner be closed to avoid strange behaviours with `Files` operations?

Comment: it closes wrapped `System.in` also that is why you are getting error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a scanner connected to `System.in` and close it, you also close `System.in`. Therefore, subsequent attempts to read from `System.in` will result in the exception you observe.

The way is avoid this is to create the Scanner only once, and never close it until your program is finished. This Scanner should be passed to whichever function needs to read from `System.in`.

Comment: Then why does another method in my program, which contains the same structure, not bump into this error?

Comment: @ylun.ca, Do you try to read after close there? If not, please share a minimum working example reproducing this.

Comment: Does returning `answer` return a `nextLine` call? @merlin2011

Comment: @ylun.ca, You will not observe the problem in the method itself, only in subsequent attempts to read from System.in. Are you calling that other method multiple times?

Comment: @ylun.ca, Is this the first call to *any* function that closes System.in directly or indirectly? If you call `handleDangerous` followed by `getRebaseAnswer`, then `getRebaseAnswer` is the **second** call.

Comment: Okay yes, then in this case `getRebaseAnswer` is the "second" call. Is this the reason?

Comment: I thought that you had to close every scanner you open, to avoid strange behaviours with file writing and reading?

Comment: @ylun.ca. Yes, because `handleDangerous` already closed `System.in`. There is **exactly one** copy of `System.in`. Once it has been closed, all functions will observe this.

Comment: @ylun.ca, That is true for Scanners connected to files, but *not* for a Scanner connected to a standard input stream. The key difference is that Files are opened by your code, while Standard Input is opened by the shell.

Comment: Is it okay that if I remove the `in.close()` eclipse starts yelling at me for a resource leak? Also, in this case, since you don't need to close the scanner until program end, should I simply create a class variable to handle console input instead?

Comment: I answered my own questions in the end, I close it at the end of `main` and yes, I created a `static final IN`

Comment: You can create a class variable if you like. Another option is to just create the scanner in main and pass it to whatever functions need it.

Answer (score 1):

don't close scanner otherwise Stream will also be closed.

```
in.close();
```

remove this line from current location and put it in main method at the end so after all the operation stream will be closed..

You might be calling some other method which have already closed the stream and then you are calling this method.